# When adding shared folder with btsync: "Don't have permissions to write to selected folder"

Tags: permissions, btsync

I am getting an error when I try to add a shared folder already on another machine also running btsync. My btsync instance on the ubuntu machine is installed using the [official linux package](http://blog.bittorrent.com/2016/02/18/official-linux-packages-for-sync-now-available/). It seems to be running with the user `btsync`. The target folder, which already exists, is under my local user name. However, I tried to share the folder to a non-existent folder name and encountered the same error.

The error, as indicated in the title, is simply: "Don't have permissions to write to selected folder."

I am not sure how to resolve this problem. It seems as though the cause may be that the btsync instance is running on a user that does not have write access to the directory in question. I suppose the problem could be solved by opening up the permissions completely (777), but that seems like a singularly bad idea.

One other thing I tried was adding the `btsync` user to my local user's group, i.e. `usermod -a -G <localuser> btsync`. That didn't work though.

Any help here would be much appreciated! Ideas?

Comment: Any time you encounter 'permission denied' when it involves the files system or installations it is likely because the operation requires root privileges, precede command with 'sudo ' 'sudo xxxxx xxxx' You will remain logged as a user, accessing root privileges as needed via 'sudo '

Answer (score 1):

If your btsync is run by the user named `btsync`, you should actually add your folder's owner to `btsync`:

```
chown -R btsync folder_name
```

Or if you're using resilio you should change folder owner to `relsync`:

```
chown -R rslsync folder_name
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. Don't know why this was downvoted, I have upvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

As BTSync team answers:

[Sync Does Not Have Permission To Access This Folder - Sync Troubleshooting - Sync Forums](https://forum.resilio.com/topic/34641-sync-does-not-have-permission-to-access-this-folder/)

> In the config file for btsync, remove the "directory_root" or
>   "dir_whitelist" parameter from the config. This parameter specifies
>   the location where Sync can create folders. You could also modify it
>   to include the specific folder you want to sync.

Here is the default sync.conf file:

```
{
    "listening_port" : 55555,
    "storage_path" : "/mnt/sync/config",
    "vendor" : "docker",
    "display_new_version": false,

    "directory_root_policy" : "belowroot",
    "directory_root" : "/mnt/",

    "webui" :
    {
        "listen" : "0.0.0.0:8888",
        "allow_empty_password" : false,
        "dir_whitelist" : [ "/mnt/sync/folders", "/mnt/mounted_folders"]
    }
}
```

you can add custum folder into `dir_whitelist`